# Is there a way to filter through a dataframe in order to return the lowest value from each category?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to figure out if there was a way to print the lowest value from each category in a dataframe. To be more clear, here's an snippet of how my dataframe looks:

```
ID Name Score  Age
1   A   15.1   21
2   A   20.5   12
3   B   15.2   18
4   B   8.2    22
5   C   43.2   12 
6   C   12.1   15
7   C   18.0   22
```

I was hoping to print the lowest score for each Unique Name. I was hoping for my dataframe to look something like this as an output:

```
ID Name Score
1  A    15.1
4  B    8.2
6  C    12.1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
df.groupby('Name')['Score'].min()
```

Since you want to keep the whole row, you use [`idxmin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html):

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Name')['Score'].idxmin()]
```

Comment: Yes I have to wait a couple of mins before accepting according to StackOverflow :)